# Is ExAllocatePool deprecated? What use instead?

Tags: windows, device-driver

I am using ExAllocatePoolWithTag and the builder warns me about ExAllocatePool being deprecated. Is this just an artifact, because the former uses the latter? If not, what is to be used instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExAllocatePool is deprecated.

ExAllocatePoolWithTag is not and should be used instead.